# jquery ajax response not sent

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that submits its content with post method to `php` script, which returns an `xml` file. I find problem in detecting what is wrong, I haven't seen any error in firefox console, this is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit( function() {
//alert('bonjour');
var pr= $('#prenom').val(); 
var te=$('#tech').val();
var sk=$('#skills').val() ; 
$("#form1").ajaxError(function(){
alert("An error occured!");
});
$.ajax({
url: "filter.php",
type: "POST",
data: { prenom: pr , tech: te , skills: sk },

dataType: "xml",
success: function(data) {
//alert(data);
$(data).find('collaborateur').each(function(){

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var urlPhoto = $(this).find('urlphoto').text();
var nb_cv = $(this).find('nb_cv').text();
var poste = $(this).find('poste').text();
var nb_ann_exp = $(this).find('nb_ann_exp').text();
var identite = $(this).find('identite').text();
var nom = $(this).find('nom').text();
var prenom = $(this).find('prenom').text();
$('<div class="items" id="link_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+urlPhoto+'"  

style="float:left">'+nom+'</a><span>'+nom+' '+prenom+'</span>').appendTo('#result');

}

);
//$('#result').html(data);
alert('Load was performed.');
},
fail: function(){alert ('fail');}
});
});
});
```

the `php` code for generating `xml` `filter.php` is below

```
 header('Content-type: text/xml');
 echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
 echo '<collaborateurs>';
 include("connection.php");
 require("functions.php");
 $tab = array();
 $tab = filter($_POST['prenom'], $_POST['tech'], $_POST['skills']);
 // print_r($tab);
 // exit;
 foreach  ($tab as $key => $value)
 {
 echo '<collaborateur id="'.$key.'">';
 echo '<nom>'.$value['nom'].'</nom>';
 echo '<prenom>'.$value['prenom'].'</prenom>';
 echo '<nb_cv>'.$value['nb_cv'].'</nb_cv>';
 echo '<poste>'.$value['poste'].'</poste>';
 echo '<nb_ann_exp>'.$value['nb_exp'].'</nb_ann_exp>';
 echo '<identite>'.$value['ident'].'</identite>';
 // echo '<nb_visite>'.$value['nb_visite'].'</nb_visite>';
 echo '</collaborateur>';
 } 
 echo '</collaborateurs>';
```

the filter function

```
function filter($pren, $tech, $comp)
{global $connection;
$tab = array();
$query="SELECT  DISTINCT c.id_c,`prenom`,`nom`,`nb_exp`,`ident`,`poste` , NomPhoto,   

nb_cv  FROM `collaborateur` c, techno_mai m , competence_cle cc  where( prenom like     

'$pren'  or (m.lib_tech like '$tech' and m.id_c =c.id_c )  or (cc.id_c = c.id_c and   

cc.lib_cc like '$comp')) ";

$c12=mysql_query($query, $connection)or die(mysql_error());
$i =0;
while($fil= mysql_fetch_array($c12))
{
$tab[$i]['prenom'] =$fil['prenom'];
$tab[$i]['nom']= $fil['nom'];
$tab[$i]['nb_exp']=$fil['nb_exp'];
$tab[$i]['ident']=$fil['ident'];
$tab[$i]['poste']=$fil['poste'];
$tab[$i]['NomPhoto']=$fil['NomPhoto'];
$tab[$i]['nb_cv']=$fil['nb_cv'];
$tab[$i]['nom']=$fil['nom'];
$tab[$i]['prenom']=$fil['prenom'];
$i++;
}
return $tab;

}
```

I tested the `php` code in a form without `ajax` and it renders a correct `xml` file.
the server output (xml file) without ajax

```
<collaborateurs>
<collaborateur id="0">
<nom>semi</nom>
<prenom>troc</prenom>
<nb_cv>0</nb_cv>
<poste>tech</poste>
<nb_ann_exp>12</nb_ann_exp>
<identite>dis</identite>
</collaborateur>
<collaborateur id="1">
<nom>tarek</nom>
<prenom>fellah</prenom>
<nb_cv>0</nb_cv>
<poste>dev</poste>
<nb_ann_exp>2</nb_ann_exp>
<identite>dev web</identite>
</collaborateur>
<collaborateur id="2">
<nom>ahmed</nom>
<prenom>hamza</prenom>
<nb_cv>0</nb_cv>
<poste>dev web</poste>
<nb_ann_exp>0</nb_ann_exp>
<identite>dev web</identite>
</collaborateur>
</collaborateurs>
```

And thanks in advance.

Comment: *//alert(data);* when uncommented, what was the output?

Comment: I see you have an alert commented as well as print_r so you tested if the server communication was right... did it work?

Comment: @Onheiron Now the event ajaxError is handled, the message "an error occured" is shown
a mithunsatheesh when uncommented nothing happen

Comment: ok, can you edit the code in your question with correct datas and ajaxError handling? oh and also that filter() function of yours, can you show it to us? what does the server output without ajax now?

Comment: are you positive on the paths you're using? like if you replace all php with echo "hello" and all success: with function(data){alert(data);} does it show up "hello" on the client?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting

```
data: { prenom: pr , te: tech , sk: skills },
```

but then retriving

```
 $tab = filter($_POST['prenom'], $_POST['tech'], $_POST['skills']);
```

should be

```
data: { prenom: pr , tech: te , skills: sk},
```

Comment: Now it works but i changed the submit event with click event, can someone tell me the origin of the problem?

Comment: if you bind on submit the submit default event will be fired anyways, thus performing the form action (or just 'refreshing' the page if no action is set). You can tell it is acting like this by the ? which appears in your page URL. You have to prevent this behaviour in order to perform your custom actions on submit event. So if you prefer using submit as event, just set the function triggered on submit to: function(e){ e.preventDefault; ... your code here...}